# Is it possible to find a word in a txt file and print the line as a string

Tags: java

I am stuck on some homework as i am new to java and still learning. I am wondering if it is possible to find a word in a .txt file and output the line that the word is on. I also need to allow a user to make a choice based on what is displayed back.

Example :

```
Word is Details
Txt file contains
Details on lion
Details on tiger
```

Output : "Details on tiger"

Thank in advanced for any help

Comment: Load the text file in a FileReader and you can read it in line by line and search each string.

Comment: Your question, as it stands now, is probably too broad.  You should try to come up with a solution in Java, and then if you get stuck come back here with a more focused question.

Comment: This can be helpful: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()

Comment: I am using a fileReader and scanner to read the text file so would i assign a variable to make it find the word? And use .contains?

Comment: You could do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been answered before, but anyway You can go with this apporach. 
Simply put:

1. Create a Scanner object and pass the required file into the
   constructor as a new file object.
2. Iterate over the file with a
   while loop until you find the specified string.
3. In order to store the lines that contains the desired word,we decalre a new string variable

Here's the code snippet:

```
Scanner scanner= new Scanner(new File("filename.txt"));
String lines = "";
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    String stringLine = scanner.nextLine();
    if(stringLine.indexOf("YOUR_WORD") != -1){
        //print whatever you want here
         System.out.println(stringLine);
      //add every line that contains stringLine into another string;
      lines+=stringLine;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this was almost what i was looking for. Is there a way to expand on this to print every line that contains the word?

Comment: You're welcome, I edited the code to fully satisfy your question. check it out

Comment: Thank you for the info i have been stuck on this for awhile

Comment: In spite of your best intentions, your answer doesn’t help the OP at all. This isn’t a site to find a babysitter. This question is so common a simple Google search turns up literally hundreds of results, but the OP chose to have someone else solve the problem. In the future, use the duplicate button instead of trying to collect points by posting redundant answers.

Comment: It's 2019, why not use String.contains()?

Comment: @Buffalo It'd be very inefficient to read the whole file as a string if all you're looking for is one matching line. What if the word is in the first line and there are a million lines in the file?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar he is using indexOf() on a single line at a time :)